# Django keycloak integrated but user delete functionaliy not working , why?

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have integrated Django with Keycloak, and I’ve set the Keycloak user ID as a foreign key for the ‘django_keycloak_user’ table. When I try to delete a user from Keycloak, I encounter an error saying, ‘user does not exist.’ I want to delete the user without affecting any dependent tables.

I have used the django-uw-keycloak 2.0.2 package.
Django = 4.1.3 and Python =3.10.12

configuration for keycloak in settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ["django_keycloak",]
MIDDLEWARE = ["django_keycloak.middleware.KeycloakMiddleware",]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "django_keycloak.authentication.KeycloakAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
    ],
]
KEYCLOAK_CONFIG = {
    # The Keycloak's Public Server URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080)
    "SERVER_URL": KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
    # The Keycloak's Internal URL
    # (e.g. http://keycloak:8080 for a docker service named keycloak)
    # Optional: Default is SERVER_URL
    "INTERNAL_URL": KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
    # Override for default Keycloak's base path
    # Default is '/auth/'
    "BASE_PATH": "/auth/",
    # The name of the Keycloak's realm
    "REALM": KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    # The ID of this client in the above Keycloak realm
    "CLIENT_ID": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    # The secret for this confidential client
    "CLIENT_SECRET_KEY": KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY,
    # The name of the admin role for the client
    "CLIENT_ADMIN_ROLE": KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_ROLE,
    # The name of the admin role for the realm
    "REALM_ADMIN_ROLE": KEYCLOAK_REALM_ADMIN_ROLE,
    # Regex formatted URLs to skip authentication
    "EXEMPT_URIS": [],
    # Flag if the token should be introspected or decoded (default is False)
    "DECODE_TOKEN": False,
    # Flag if the audience in the token should be verified (default is True)
    "VERIFY_AUDIENCE": True,
    # Flag if the user info has been included in the token (default is True)
    "USER_INFO_IN_TOKEN": True,
    # Flag to show the traceback of debug logs (default is False)
    "TRACE_DEBUG_LOGS": False,
    # The token prefix that is expected in Authorization header (default is 'Bearer')
    "TOKEN_PREFIX": "Bearer",
}

CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "sync_users_with_keycloak": {
        "task": "django_keycloak.tasks.sync_users_with_keycloak",
        "schedule": timedelta(hours=2),
        "options": {"queue": f"sync-users-{ENVIRONMENT}"},
    },
}
```

In the cart model, I have used ForeignKey on user cart.py

```
from django_keycloak.models import KeycloakUser
class Cart(CMSMixin, TimeStampMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        KeycloakUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True
    )
```

if I delete the user from Keycloak, error will show **user not found**

```
KeycloakGetError at /iam/users/
404: b'{"error":"User not found"}'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://abc.ser.h.in/iam/users/?ordering=id&page=1&page_size=100
Django Version: 4.2.4
Exception Type: KeycloakGetError
Exception Value:    
404: b'{"error":"User not found"}'
Exception Location: /root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keycloak/exceptions.py, line 192, in raise_error_from_response
Raised during:  iam.views.KeycloakUserViewSet
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/python
Python Version: 3.10.13
Python Path:    
['/src',
 '/src',
 '/root/.local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 04 Nov 2023 11:12:51 +0530
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py, line 55, in inner
        return inner
    else:
        @wraps(get_response)
        def inner(request):
            try:
                response = get_response(request) …
            except Exception as exc:
                response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
            return response
        return inner
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 197, in _get_response
        if response is None:
            wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
            # If it is an asynchronous view, run it in a subthread.
            if iscoroutinefunction(wrapped_callback):
                wrapped_callback = async_to_sync(wrapped_callback)
            try:
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
            except Exception as e:
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
                if response is None:
                    raise
        # Complain if the view returned None (a common error).
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py, line 84, in sentry_wrapped_callback
            # this isn't necessary for async views since that runs on main
            if sentry_scope.profile is not None:
                sentry_scope.profile.update_active_thread_id()
            with hub.start_span(
                op=OP.VIEW_RENDER, description=request.resolver_match.view_name
            ):
                return callback(request, *args, **kwargs) …
    return sentry_wrapped_callback
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py, line 79, in inner
        """
        return self
    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwds):
            with self._recreate_cm():
                return func(*args, **kwds) …
        return inner
class AsyncContextDecorator(object):
    "A base class or mixin that enables async context managers to work as decorators."
Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py, line 79, in inner
        """
        return self
    def __call__(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwds):
            with self._recreate_cm():
                return func(*args, **kwds) …
        return inner
class AsyncContextDecorator(object):
    "A base class or mixin that enables async context managers to work as decorators."
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py, line 56, in wrapper_view
def csrf_exempt(view_func):
    """Mark a view function as being exempt from the CSRF view protection."""
    # view_func.csrf_exempt = True would also work, but decorators are nicer
    # if they don't have side effects, so return a new function.
    @wraps(view_func)
    def wrapper_view(*args, **kwargs):
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs) …
    wrapper_view.csrf_exempt = True
    return wrapper_view
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py, line 125, in view
                setattr(self, method, handler)
            self.request = request
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs
            # And continue as usual
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) …
        # take name and docstring from class
        update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
        # and possible attributes set by decorators
        # like csrf_exempt from dispatch
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 509, in dispatch
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc) …
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
    def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 469, in handle_exception
        exception_handler = self.get_exception_handler()
        context = self.get_exception_handler_context()
        response = exception_handler(exc, context)
        if response is None:
            self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc) …
        response.exception = True
        return response
    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):
        if settings.DEBUG:
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    def raise_uncaught_exception(self, exc):
        if settings.DEBUG:
            request = self.request
            renderer_format = getattr(request.accepted_renderer, 'format')
            use_plaintext_traceback = renderer_format not in ('html', 'api', 'admin')
            request.force_plaintext_errors(use_plaintext_traceback)
        raise exc …
    # Note: Views are made CSRF exempt from within `as_view` as to prevent
    # accidental removal of this exemption in cases where `dispatch` needs to
    # be overridden.
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py, line 506, in dispatch
            # Get the appropriate handler method
            if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
                handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(),
                                  self.http_method_not_allowed)
            else:
                handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
            response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs) …
        except Exception as exc:
            response = self.handle_exception(exc)
        self.response = self.finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
        return self.response
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py, line 43, in list
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data) …
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
class RetrieveModelMixin:
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 768, in data
        return representation.list_repr(self, indent=1)
    # Include a backlink to the serializer class on return objects.
    # Allows renderers such as HTMLFormRenderer to get the full field info.
    @property
    def data(self):
        ret = super().data …
        return ReturnList(ret, serializer=self)
    @property
    def errors(self):
        ret = super().errors
        if isinstance(ret, list) and len(ret) == 1 and getattr(ret[0], 'code', None) == 'null':
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 253, in data
                'You should either call `.is_valid()` first, '
                'or access `.initial_data` instead.'
            )
            raise AssertionError(msg)
        if not hasattr(self, '_data'):
            if self.instance is not None and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
                self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance) …
            elif hasattr(self, '_validated_data') and not getattr(self, '_errors', None):
                self._data = self.to_representation(self.validated_data)
            else:
                self._data = self.get_initial()
        return self._data
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 686, in to_representation
        """
        List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        return [ …
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]
    def validate(self, attrs):
        return attrs
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 687, in <listcomp>
        List of object instances -> List of dicts of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data
        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable …
        ]
    def validate(self, attrs):
        return attrs
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 522, in to_representation
            #
            # For related fields with `use_pk_only_optimization` we need to
            # resolve the pk value.
            check_for_none = attribute.pk if isinstance(attribute, PKOnlyObject) else attribute
            if check_for_none is None:
                ret[field.field_name] = None
            else:
                ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute) …
        return ret
    def validate(self, attrs):
        return attrs
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py, line 509, in to_representation
        Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        ret = OrderedDict()
        fields = self._readable_fields
        for field in fields:
            try:
                attribute = field.get_attribute(instance) …
            except SkipField:
                continue
            # We skip `to_representation` for `None` values so that fields do
            # not have to explicitly deal with that case.
            #
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py, line 446, in get_attribute
    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        """
        Given the *outgoing* object instance, return the primitive value
        that should be used for this field.
        """
        try:
            return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs) …
        except BuiltinSignatureError as exc:
            msg = (
                'Field source for `{serializer}.{field}` maps to a built-in '
                'function type and is invalid. Define a property or method on '
                'the `{instance}` instance that wraps the call to the built-in '
                'function.'.format(
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py, line 96, in get_attribute
    Also accepts either attribute lookup on objects or dictionary lookups.
    """
    for attr in attrs:
        try:
            if isinstance(instance, Mapping):
                instance = instance[attr]
            else:
                instance = getattr(instance, attr) …
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
        if is_simple_callable(instance):
            try:
                instance = instance()
            except (AttributeError, KeyError) as exc:
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_keycloak/models.py, line 69, in first_name
    @property
    def email(self):
        self._confirm_cache()
        return self._cached_user_info.get("email")
    @property
    def first_name(self):
        self._confirm_cache() …
        return self._cached_user_info.get("firstName")
    @property
    def last_name(self):
        self._confirm_cache()
        return self._cached_user_info.get("lastName")
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_keycloak/models.py, line 79, in _confirm_cache
    @property
    def last_name(self):
        self._confirm_cache()
        return self._cached_user_info.get("lastName")
    def _confirm_cache(self):
        if not self._cached_user_info:
            self._cached_user_info = lazy_keycloak_admin.get_user(self.id) …
class AbstractKeycloakUserAutoId(AbstractKeycloakUser):
    """
    This AbstractModel uses the default django AutoIncrement field as the PK,
    opposed to the AbstractKeycloakUser which uses keycloak_id as the table PK.
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keycloak/keycloak_admin.py, line 868, in get_user
        :param user_id: User id
        :type user_id: str
        :return: UserRepresentation
        """
        params_path = {"realm-name": self.connection.realm_name, "id": user_id}
        data_raw = self.connection.raw_get(urls_patterns.URL_ADMIN_USER.format(**params_path))
        return raise_error_from_response(data_raw, KeycloakGetError) …
    def get_user_groups(self, user_id, query=None, brief_representation=True):
        """Get user groups.
        Returns a list of groups of which the user is a member
Local vars
/root/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keycloak/exceptions.py, line 192, in raise_error_from_response
    if isinstance(error, dict):
        error = error.get(response.status_code, KeycloakOperationError)
    else:
        if response.status_code == 401:
            error = KeycloakAuthenticationError
    raise error( …
        error_message=message, response_code=response.status_code, response_body=response.content
    )
```